# how to do a multiple selection from the databse using nhibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, jstree, dataview

I need to show the result of a multiple selection and do not know how I can handle, the problem is as follows:

I have a tree, which is multipleselection, selecting the first time, this shows me the correct information, but when I select another node, the information should be displayed for the first and the second selection, but only show the second.

My question is, how I can store the previous selection and link this with the new one ..? I'm working with NHibernate, C # and the MVC model.

I appreciate any help.

Sincerely

Comment: somebody told me that it could be handle with dataviews, but i don't know how..

Answer (score 0):

you can Query for multiple Selections

```
IEnumerable<Entity> results = Enumerable.Empty<Entity>();

foreach (var node in selectedNodes)
{
    results = results.Concat(Session.Query<Entity>().Where(...).Future<Entity>());
}

Show(results);
```

Or cache the results of selections

```
Dictionary<node, IEnumerable<Entity>> _nodeResults; // somewhere


foreach (var node in selectedNodes)
{
    if (!_nodeResults.ContainsKey(node))
        _nodeResults.Add(node, Session.Query<Entity>().Where(...).Future<Entity>());

    results = results.Concat(_nodeResults[node]);
}
```

if you need distinct results use `Intersect` instead of `Concat` or use `Show(results.Distinct());`